# CakePHP, CodeIgniter and FuelPHP - which do you prefer and why?

Tags: php, frameworks

I've been looking into learning a PHP framework lately and have spotted these three popular choices. They all seem to have similar approaches and methods, and I'm not sure where to begin. If you are or have been using either one I'd greatly appreciate any pros, cons or other info you might want to share about them.

I'm considering these frameworks with the following in mind:
- Which one has best multi-lingual support?
- Which is the easiest to implement / start out with?
- Which is the most future-proof and versatile (i.e. working with NoSQL databases such as MongoDB)?

Comment: I asked the same to myself some time ago. My suggestion: play a little bit with them and choose what really fits your needs and you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Don't know about the others, but using codeigniter because of royalty free licence ;)

Comment: This is a subjective question, so will probably be closed. But fwiw I'd add Symfony and Zend in there as well. I thought symfony 1.0.x was great, found the forms framework of 1.1.x too complicated, and do really need to make time to learn Symfony 2.0 from scratch. I think the forms stuff has been simplified a great deal, and afaik is the only PHP framework to use the dependency injection approach from the ground up.

Comment: maybe you should look into [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) too. i was a total php noob, and in a month or less i started developing my final project for college using zend and doctrine (an ORM for php), and i gotta tell you i'm loving it

Comment: If your really interested in multilingual support, take a look at Symfony (http://symfony.com). A large portion of the core team is from france, so it its designed to work with localization.

Comment: halfer & PiTheNumber: I know. And I'm ignoring it. Not being able to discuss frameworks on a developer forum is just silly (even if there isn't a "right answer").

Comment: I can't see any framework being better/worse at interfacing with NoSQL dbs. Presumably that just requires a PHP library, which should just drop into (and autoload in) any of the frameworks on this page.

Comment: MrGlass & jere: Great tips, thanks! Will look into these as well. Adds up to the confusion though...

Comment: @StaffanEstberg - new posters should tread on the rules carefully, rather than trample! ;-)

Comment: halfer: Yeah... I will probably get a kick in the butt for this....

Comment: I've found most jobs look for zend experience; so it's good to have. But personally I think once you get to grips with at least one, you can easily adapt to others - as they share similar principles. I started out with codeignitor, which is a piece of cake but very good.

Comment: @StaffanEstberg you're welcome. give me a shout if you need any tips

Answer (score 2):

I have been using all of the mentioned frameworks, but I really enjoy using the codeigniter framework, because it is very lightweight and does not interfere with my workflow in doing too much things I don't want.
The i18n and multi-lingual support is really simple, there is a helper and a class ready to use.
Codeigniter has also pretty much support for any database you may want to use. If you happen to use a database that isn't supported, you can easily write your own database driver, just take a look at one of the driver files.
It is also very easy to integrate other external libraries e.g. Doctrine, adodb into your project.

Comment: @Herr Kaleun Please use English so that everyone can follow without having Google Translate open in tab...